# Why does the "trilobite" have teeth?

Tags: prometheus

In the octopus form, we see teeth but its sole purpose is to implant in a host -- when would it use those teeth? It has no desire to injure the host. One could argue that it could defend itself against threats but it already has tentacles.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no way to say for certain there are several possibilities

The creature is an engineered life form it could be as simple as it was easier to leave the teeth in the genome than it would have been to remove them

The likeliest answer however is that while its main purpose is to implant a host it may have to fight to be able to do so, we only see it on a one on one fight with a single engineer but if there were multiple opponents it would have to kill or disable them before it could implant one of them seeing as how it seems the implanting process takes most of its attention.

Comment: Yes although I wonder to what extent it has the brains to do anything other than impregnate.